# Way to get around stack size

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

So I have this recursive factorial function in c#. I am using it to deal with `BigInteger`. The problem arises when I want to deal with large integers and because my function is recursive it will cause a `StackOverflow` exception. Now the simple solution is to not make the function recursive. I am wondering if there is a way to get around this? I'm thinking along the lines of more ram allocated the the stack?

```
BigInteger Factorial(BigInteger n)
{
    return n == 1 ? 1 : n * Factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: You don't need a stack to compute a factorial; neither a call stack nor a Stack<T>. Why insist on having one?

Comment: Wrong tool. It turns factorial from O(1) space into O(n) space. You'd need tail call optimization to implement it in O(1) with recursion, which C# does not provide. If you convert your code into tail call form, you're half way to the iterative solution.

Comment: Recursive algorithms are only appropriate if the complexity is no more than O(log(n)) or the depth is bounded by a reasonable number.  Neither applies.  This isn't otherwise a problem that really needs a solution, Calc.exe gets that job done too.

Answer (score 1):

I understand it is nice if you could express recursive functions in c# without worrying about the stack. But unfortunately that is not directly possible, and no matter how big you make the stack there will always be situations where you run out of stack space. Furthermore your performance will likely be pretty horrendous. If you have a tail recursive function like this factorial something can be done, that pretty much lets you express your function in the original recursive way, without the huge penalty.

Unfortunately c# does not directly support tail recursive calls, but workarounds are possible using a so-called "trampoline" construction.

See for example: http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2009/11/08/jumping-the-trampoline-in-c-stack-friendly-recursion.aspx and http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/09/02/tail-recursion-in-c/

From the last blog, comes the following code that will allow you to perform the factorial as a tail recursive function without stack problems.

```
public static class TailRecursion
{
    public static T Execute<T>(Func<RecursionResult<T>> func)
    {
        do
        {
            var recursionResult = func();
            if (recursionResult.IsFinalResult)
                return recursionResult.Result;
            func = recursionResult.NextStep;
        } while (true);
    }

    public static RecursionResult<T> Return<T>(T result)
    {
        return new RecursionResult<T>(true, result, null);
    }

    public static RecursionResult<T> Next<T>(Func<RecursionResult<T>> nextStep)
    {
        return new RecursionResult<T>(false, default(T), nextStep);
    }

}

public class RecursionResult<T>
{
    private readonly bool _isFinalResult;
    private readonly T _result;
    private readonly Func<RecursionResult<T>> _nextStep;
    internal RecursionResult(bool isFinalResult, T result, Func<RecursionResult<T>> nextStep)
    {
        _isFinalResult = isFinalResult;
        _result = result;
        _nextStep = nextStep;
    }

    public bool IsFinalResult { get { return _isFinalResult; } }
    public T Result { get { return _result; } }
    public Func<RecursionResult<T>> NextStep { get { return _nextStep; } }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BigInteger result = TailRecursion.Execute(() => Factorial(50000, 1));
    }

    static RecursionResult<BigInteger> Factorial(int n, BigInteger product)
    {
        if (n < 2)
            return TailRecursion.Return(product);
        return TailRecursion.Next(() => Factorial(n - 1, n * product));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new thread with the stacksize you want...

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<BigInteger>();
int stackSize = 1024*1024*1024;

new Thread(() =>
    {
        tcs.SetResult(Factorial(10000));
    },stackSize)
    .Start();

var result = tcs.Task.Result;
```

But as mentioned in comments, an iterative way for this would be better..